# Format date with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to format `06-06-2013 1:51 PM` as `Jun 06,2013`.

I have tried all possible different formatting styles using `NSDateFormatter` but failed.

Comment: 06-06-2013 1:51 PM is this NSString or NSDate ?

Comment: I doubt you've tried **all possible combinations**. Show us a couple of the ones you did.

Comment: @Rahul it is NSString

Comment: @Abizem: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateString  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

Comment: @Abizem: dateFromString returning nil

Comment: A similar question has been asked over and over and over and over and over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
        First You need to convert this string back to NSDate then again convert the NSdate to string using formatter.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatForDB = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatForDB setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a"]; //Note capital H is 4 24-hour time format
    NSDate *aDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:[dateFormatForDB dateFromString:aDateString]] autorelease];
   if(aDate){
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy"];
     NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:aDate];
     [dateFormatForDB release];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this format

```
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy];
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your format, i think this is what you are looking for...

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *newDate = [df dateFromString:dateString];
NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df2 setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy"];
NSString *formattedDate = [df2 stringFromDate:newDate];
```

This will give you the date as string in the required format. If you want time in 24hr format, replace 'hh' with 'HH'.